# How do I delete a font in IntelliJ?

Tags: windows, intellij-idea

I am trying to replace the Inconsolata font with its older version in IntelliJ (the newer version added things that I'm not happy with)

IntelliJ seemingly refused to remove a font that I wish to be removed.

The font in question is Inconsolata, and the picture below shows me trying to delete it. It works, at this stage.

[image]

However, after doing that, and restarting the PC, IntelliJ insists that the font exists.

[image]

It will give a strange name to the font, but the entry exists. This causes problem on my end - there's some reference caching the IntelliJ is doing, and if I were to replace the font with the older version, it'll still be using the newer cache, but will give a strange output if the cache is pointing to something that doesn't exists.

I've tried

- Deleting the settings folder
- Reinstalling IntelliJ and then restarting

Is there a way to delete a font in IntelliJ properly?

Comment: @halil I did `Invalidate and Restart`. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like Windows doesn't properly delete a font. Unfortunately, this causes problems for some apps.

### The fix

1. Head towards `C:\Windows\Fonts` from your terminal. Do not use a file browser, as that will open up the control panel item.
2. Delete all traces of inconsolata (There was Inconsolata-Bold.ttf, Inconsolata-Regular.ttf, inconsolata.otf) using a terminal

Now your IDE will no longer have the Inconsolata font.

[image]

Comment: if you try and remove a font that a program is actively using it will not work correctly because of brain dead way windows deals with file locks and handles. this is not a problem on other *nix platforms.

Comment: Could the downvoter explain the downvote? This solution works for me (that's why I wrote it in the first place)

@JarrodRoberson : Windows won't allow the user to delete the font through the Font panel if it's being used. In this case, I did manage to delete the font (windows allowed it) but after hunting for Inconsolata in my filesystem, I accidentally found out that the font is still there, inside the `C:\Windows\Fonts` folder